# filtrar por fecha y hora mysql

Tags: mysql

estoy haciendo un programita del tiempo y necesito obtener de la bd las líneas que estén entre el día 22 y 28 y que estos sean a las 11:00, ya que cada día tiene varias horas y solo necesito de cada día uno.

`` SELECT * FROM `datos` WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-22' AND '2021-09-28' ``

[image: Consigo lo siguiente]

Y quiero que solo me salgan los que son a las 11:00:00

He intentado esto:
`` SELECT * FROM `datos` WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-22' AND '2021-09-28' and fecha LIKE '11:00:00' ``

Pero no devuelve nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

específicamente para lo que tu pones te recomiendo LIKE

```
select * from datos where fecha like '2021-09-2% 11:00';
```

esto es especifico para que lo que necesitas, pero dudo mucho que lo puedas aplicar para algo mas que no sea lo que pediste ahorita

Comment: las consultas de fecha con horas es mejor buscarlas por un rango entre fecha inicio y fecha fin. En vez de un like que no tienes ningun rango alli y se te puede colar otra fecha que no toque. Ya que el Like lo que realiza es buscame en el campo fecha que contenga X valor.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo uqe haria es entre rango de fechas

```
select * from datos where fecha>='2021-09-22 11:00:00' and fecha<='2021-09-29 11:00:00'
```

Asi obtienes el rango de fechas en vez de un like que se te puede pasar alguna fecha de mas.

Comment: consideraste la hora ?  se van a filtrar fechas que tengan la hora mayor o menor que 11:00.

Comment: Puse la hora porque Samuel Marquez le estaba haciendo un Like por la hora en su consulta.